# Chrome 59 hangs with --headless and --proxy-server flag

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So now that Chrome 59 has headless support
and a proper driver for it (Chromedriver 2.30),
I tried migrating my code to it.

--headless flag works by itself.
--proxy-server flag works by itself, however
combining the two hangs the browser.

Is there a workaround for it?

Env:
  - Chrome 59
  - Chromedriver 2.30
  - selenium 2.46.0

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chop.add_argument("--headless")
chop.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080")
d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
print("done")
d.get('http://ipinfo.io')
print(d.page_source)
```

Traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "t.py", line 5, in <module>
        d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
      File "/home/t/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
        keep_alive=True)
      File "/home/t/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
        self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "/home/t/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 138, in start_session
        'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
      File "/home/t/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/home/t/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: looks like a bug.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1843&q=proxy&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This bug has been resolved.**
I just tested it with the follow setup:

Ubuntu 16.04   64 bit
Google Chrome 61.0.3163.59 **beta**  (official release still hangs atm;)
Selenium  3.5.0
ChromeDriver 2.31

No more xvfb required.
I am a happy man today.